# AJAX error 303 handling

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter, error-handling

I'm using ajax to send values to another form. There, I insert in DB and return the table as html to update instantly. So far it's a simple ajax refresh the table.
The problem is, I check the session to be logged in and do that things. when i delete the cookie (the session timeout) the login page shows in the partial form that should shows the returned table.
I checked... it seems has the "303 see other!" error.
I need it to redirect to login page when the session is times out.

Here is my ajax code:

```
function save(){
    var value = {
      //values
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<?php echo site_url('admin/test'); ?>',
        data: value,
        success: function(resp){
            $('#sample_1').html(resp);
        },
    });
}
```

I check the session in the admin controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use jQuery `ajax()` `statusCode` handler like so:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '<?php echo site_url('admin/test'); ?>',
    data: value,
    success: function(resp){
        $('#sample_1').html(resp);
    },
    statusCode: {
        303: function() {
           ...do stuff you want to do when 303 happens...
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Here is the files and status:
http://uupload.ir/files/noon_ajax.jpg
It shows 303 error but with error handling in ajax or the code you've write, I can't get the error.